# stuck in react native props - onSubmitEditing and onChangeText in <TextInput>

Tags: react-native, textinput

When I used onSubmitEditing in TextInput and pressed submit button than I found an undefined result in the console onChangeText worked but I want to put onSubmitEditing

```js
<View>
  <Text>Name of Industry </Text>
  <TextInput
    placeholder='Your Answer'
    onSubmitEditing={txtHandler1}
  />
</View>
```

Comment: onSubmitEditing is called when you click on return button or equivalent on the keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

`onSubmitEditing` is called when the text input's submit button is pressed. The submit button can be return key or can be different based on `returnKeyType` props or vice versa. I am not sure what you want to do?

You should send the text value to the `txtHandler1`

```
<View>
  <Text>Name of Industry </Text>
  <TextInput
   placeholder='Your Answer'
   onSubmitEditing={(event)=> txtHandler1(event.nativeEvent.text)}
  />
</View>
```

You can also use `onEndEditing` props instead of `onSubmitEditing` which will called when text input ends.

`onEndEditing={(event)=> txtHandler1(event.nativeEvent.text)}`